# NTFS permissions set to inherit, but don't apply to new files

Tags: permissions, ntfs, onedrive, smb, ownership

I'm running into a really frustrating issue with inheritance for NTFS permissions not working correctly.

I use cloud storage (specifically OneDrive) for storage of certain files; in this case, I have a client on my laptop and want to be able to access the files on my desktop, too.

On the laptop, the client is on the computer normally, but I don't run the client on the desktop since cloud storage clients are RAM and CPU hogs and I don't want that running on my workstation. Instead, I have a VM on a server (sitting next to the workstation) that runs a virtual machine for cloud storage clients and some other file shares. The cloud storage folders are then mapped to the workstation using SMB, like any other file share. The VM is on 24/7 while the desktop I sometimes put to sleep, such as overnight.

I used to be doing this on Windows 7 and it worked fine. I only "upgraded" that VM to Windows 10 recently due to Microsoft force-obsolescing that capability by discontinuing OneDrive support for Windows 7 next month. Otherwise, I would move back to that known working setup.

The issue I'm having now is that when I create new files outside of this setup (e.g. on the laptop or online), the files sync to the VM but when I try to access them from the desktop, "Access is denied". (The desktop is running Windows 7, but the issue isn't on the desktop, it's on the VM).

The way it is set up is there is a non-interactive user configured on the VM with Full Control SMB and NTFS permissions to all the relevant folders, which is used on the drive mapping on the desktop. The NTFS permissions are set to inherit.

However, when a new file shows up on the VM that it didn't create, the permissions don't inherit. It is just set to allow SYSTEM, admin, and Administrators full control.

Last week, to try to fix this, in addition to adding the standard user as full control, I also added "Users" to full control, just in case one of the permissions failed.

But that doesn't work; *both* of these permissions fail to inherit, and since I don't map the drives as admin, I get "Access Denied".

Short of actually having the standard user used for mapping take ownership of the OneDrive directory (which is owned by `admin` since it runs as that user), is there any way to fix this permission fiasco? I have gone to the top-level directory and re-applied the NTFS permissions to add the additional users multiple times now, and it will fix files that were recently added, of course, but still fails to apply to future files. It seems like something is seriously broken here.

Essentially, whenever this happens, I need to RDP into the VM and manually fix the permissions on the new file. This is completely untenable.

The only difference here I can think of is on the old virtual machine, the path to OneDrive was `C:\OneDrive`, and now it's the default, `C:\Users\admin\OneDrive`. But the permissions have been set properly, so it should work.

The VM doesn't do anything else, so as a last resort I am fine with just setting the NTFS permissions to everybody, since the SMB permissions don't have any issues, but it seems like that shouldn't be necessary. Any suggestions for fixing this?

I should add that the main reason I don't want to "Take Ownership" of the directory with the other user is because the problem could very well happen in reverse, i.e. for some reason, the inherited rights of `admin` to that folder might break and then `admin` would not be allowed full control access to its own OneDrive directory. I need a foolproof guaranteed way to ensure that both users have Full Control.

**Other Observations:**

This does seem perhaps to be some bug either with OneDrive and/or Windows 10.

- Moving the `OneDrive` folder to `C:\OneDrive` as opposed to `C:\Users\admin\OneDrive` (and re-applying NTFS permissions and recreating the shares) does *not* fix the problem.
- Dropbox does not have this issue.
- This same arrangement worked fine on Windows 7 with no issue.

I don't think this worked before, but if I create text files on the laptop and try to access them on the desktop, *that* seems to work. However, the same is never true with PDFs; I always get "Access Denied" with those.

The **only** thing that works is, you guessed it: mapping the shares as admin, and adding `admin` on the VM to the SMB permissions.

I'm not super happy about that arrangement, but I'm the only user of these machines anyways so the security doesn't really matter either way, so it works as a sloppy workaround for now. (The original problem, though, remains: incompatibility with accessing the files as someone other than the user running the programs on the VM).

Comment: I would assume that the file is explicitly created with disabled inherited permission. Therefore most likely the OneDrive client is programmed to create files this way. As a workaround you could run a powershell script on that VM that waits for new files and corrects the permissions. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell

Comment: @Robert See, the thing is it *does* inherit the default inherited properties, SYSTEM, Administrators, and admin, and shows them all as being inherited from C:\Users\admin. What it doesn't inherit is the permissions I set at C:\Users\admin\OneDrive, then set to propagate downwards from there. Wouldn't we expect it to either inherit everything or nothing?